# Search custom object records

Tags: search, global-search

I have a custom object and I am unable to get its records in the result even when I do a global search on its exact name. Please note that:

1. The custom object has a tab and it is in 'default off' for all profiles
2. Allow search has been ticked on the object.

Comment: The object was a detail in a master detail and I was able to see the master. Found out that I could obtain the result by clicking on 'Search All' hence was able to find out why. Thanks @Girbot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to obtain the records when I clicked on the 'Search All' but not the 'Search'. This is due to the fast that salesforce did not detect much activity in that object and hence did not give importance to it. After clicking 'Search All' there appears a list of objects on the left hand side and each of those objects has a pin to its right. Clicking on the pin ensures that the object is given due importance and its results are shown in the next search without having to click 'Search All'.